# Python 3.4: using pip

Tags: matplotlib, pip, python-3.4

I've read in the documentation that Python3.4 ships with `pip` installed. When I try to make a call however I get an error. What am I missing?

```
U:\>py -V
Python 3.4.2

U:\>py -3.4 -m pip install matplotlib
C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: what happens if you try `py -m ensurepip`?

Comment: @cel That fixed it, besides bringing to light some unrelated dependency issues for matplotlib. Thank you!